# How to reference pull request in another pull request or commit message with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Suppose I make a new clean PR after hot debates in the previous draft PR which was mostly created for discussion and is too bulk and dirty to merge. In this new PR I want to make a reference to that draft PR for easy traceability of the original discussion and decisions taken.

With GitHub I would simply use an integer number with `#`, because GitHub uses the same range of ids used for everything: issues, discussions, PRs. The same trick does not work in Azure. If I try to link another PR with `#` I get a link to a work item, which obviously does not exists (because I did not mean to reference a work item).
Is there any way to link PR in another PR or Git commit message?

I will probably get a suggestion to link both PRs to the work item, but in my current scenario I do not have a work item at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `!` or the "Mention a pull request" button to mention other PR in the Description or the Discussion field of one PR.

For example:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Works everywhere, including commit messages.